# Building a language model using tensorflow , dataset shape issue

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a translation model, so I'm getting a text as input, I'm encoding him to a list of integers (the type of enocding is not important).so far so good.
let's say this is what I have so far:

```
<class 'list'>: [1645, 3, 205, 753, 753, 1332, 18, 7, 7, 24]
```

Now I want to do this lines:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(encoded_txt)

ds = ds.batch(32)
```

(btw why do we need the first line, just to be able to do the second?)

But from this lines I'm getting:

> shape=(?,32)

and I don't understand why? 
I have a batch size of 32 and 10 numbers,
why isn't it (1,32) (with paddings or something)???

This impacts me after on in the code, I really need to understand how to handle this.

btw just reshape isn't working :(

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information about your input data (e.g. how the encoded_txt tensor looks like) and what you want to get in the end. Also, I don't get what that list object is supposed to be.

Comment: It's supposed to be a list of int, 10 words -> 10 ints.
The encoding is too long to attach. if you want to see I can give you a link to github, but really I dont think it's taht important.